# Adding different color to every countries in map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got a map from http://jvectormap.com/ I want to add different different colors to every countries.How can i add colors to this. It has only color sclae how to do this? Any help please..

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){
  var $ = jQuery;

  $('#focus-single').click(function(){
    $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {region: 'AU', animate: true});
  });
  $('#focus-multiple').click(function(){
    $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {regions: ['AU', 'JP'], animate: true});
  });
  $('#focus-coords').click(function(){
    $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 7, lat: 35, lng: 33, animate: true});
  });
  $('#focus-init').click(function(){
    $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 1, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, animate: true});
  });
  $('#map1').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    panOnDrag: true,
    focusOn: {
      x: 0.5,
      y: 0.5,
      scale: 2,
      animate: true
    },


    series: {
      regions: [{
        scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        values: {
          "AF": 16.63,
          "AL": 11.58,
          "DZ": 158.97,
          "AO": 85.81,
          "AG": 1.1,
          "AR": 351.02,
          "AM": 8.83,
          "AU": 1219.72,
          "AT": 366.26,
          "AZ": 52.17,
          "BS": 7.54,
          "BH": 21.73,
          "BD": 105.4,
          "BB": 3.96,
          "BY": 52.89,
          "BE": 461.33,
          "BZ": 1.43,
          "BJ": 6.49,
          "BT": 1.4,
          "BO": 19.18,
          "BA": 16.2,
          "BW": 12.5,
          "BR": 2023.53,
          "BN": 11.96,
          "BG": 44.84,
          "BF": 8.67,
          "BI": 1.47,
          "KH": 11.36,
          "CM": 21.88,
          "CA": 1563.66,
          "CV": 1.57,
          "CF": 2.11,
          "TD": 7.59,
          "CL": 199.18,
          "CN": 5745.13,
          "CO": 283.11,
          "KM": 0.56,
          "CD": 12.6,
          "CG": 11.88,
          "CR": 35.02,
          "CI": 22.38,
          "HR": 59.92,
          "CY": 22.75,
          "CZ": 195.23,
          "DK": 304.56,
          "DJ": 1.14,
          "DM": 0.38,
          "DO": 50.87,
          "EC": 61.49,
          "EG": 216.83,
          "SV": 21.8,
          "GQ": 14.55,
          "ER": 2.25,
          "EE": 19.22,
          "ET": 30.94,
          "FJ": 3.15,
          "FI": 231.98,
          "FR": 2555.44,
          "GA": 12.56,
          "GM": 1.04,
          "GE": 11.23,
          "DE": 3305.9,
          "GH": 18.06,
          "GR": 305.01,
          "GD": 0.65,
          "GT": 40.77,
          "GN": 4.34,
          "GW": 0.83,
          "GY": 2.2,
          "HT": 6.5,
          "HN": 15.34,
          "HK": 226.49,
          "HU": 132.28,
          "IS": 12.77,
          "IN": 1430.02,
          "ID": 695.06,
          "IR": 337.9,
          "IQ": 84.14,
          "IE": 204.14,
          "IL": 201.25,
          "IT": 2036.69,
          "JM": 13.74,
          "JP": 5390.9,
          "JO": 27.13,
          "KZ": 129.76,
          "KE": 32.42,
          "KI": 0.15,
          "KR": 986.26,
          "KW": 117.32,
          "KG": 4.44,
          "LA": 6.34,
          "LV": 23.39,
          "LB": 39.15,
          "LS": 1.8,
          "LR": 0.98,
          "LY": 77.91,
          "LT": 35.73,
          "LU": 52.43,
          "MK": 9.58,
          "MG": 8.33,
          "MW": 5.04,
          "MY": 218.95,
          "MV": 1.43,
          "ML": 9.08,
          "MT": 7.8,
          "MR": 3.49,
          "MU": 9.43,
          "MX": 1004.04,
          "MD": 5.36,
          "MN": 5.81,
          "ME": 3.88,
          "MA": 91.7,
          "MZ": 10.21,
          "MM": 35.65,
          "NA": 11.45,
          "NP": 15.11,
          "NL": 770.31,
          "NZ": 138,
          "NI": 6.38,
          "NE": 5.6,
          "NG": 206.66,
          "NO": 413.51,
          "OM": 53.78,
          "PK": 174.79,
          "PA": 27.2,
          "PG": 8.81,
          "PY": 17.17,
          "PE": 153.55,
          "PH": 189.06,
          "PL": 438.88,
          "PT": 223.7,
          "QA": 126.52,
          "RO": 158.39,
          "RU": 1476.91,
          "RW": 5.69,
          "WS": 0.55,
          "ST": 0.19,
          "SA": 434.44,
          "SN": 12.66,
          "RS": 38.92,
          "SC": 0.92,
          "SL": 1.9,
          "SG": 217.38,
          "SK": 86.26,
          "SI": 46.44,
          "SB": 0.67,
          "ZA": 354.41,
          "ES": 1374.78,
          "LK": 48.24,
          "KN": 0.56,
          "LC": 1,
          "VC": 0.58,
          "SD": 65.93,
          "SR": 3.3,
          "SZ": 3.17,
          "SE": 444.59,
          "CH": 522.44,
          "SY": 59.63,
          "TW": 426.98,
          "TJ": 5.58,
          "TZ": 22.43,
          "TH": 312.61,
          "TL": 0.62,
          "TG": 3.07,
          "TO": 0.3,
          "TT": 21.2,
          "TN": 43.86,
          "TR": 729.05,
          "TM": 0,
          "UG": 17.12,
          "UA": 136.56,
          "AE": 239.65,
          "GB": 2258.57,
          "US": 14624.18,
          "UY": 40.71,
          "UZ": 37.72,
          "VU": 0.72,
          "VE": 285.21,
          "VN": 101.99,
          "YE": 30.02,
          "ZM": 15.69,
          "ZW": 5.57
        }
      }]
    }
  });
})
```

Can add color something like this for every countries by using country id?

```
 scale: ['"AF":{color: "#00a49a",hover_color: "#06756e",},'],
```

**[Fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/o0tughL0/)**

Please give a help

Answer (score 1):

There is example code on the jvectormap.com

> "...that demonstrates how to set colors directly for the map. The map is painted to the random colors upon loading."

http://jvectormap.com/examples/random-colors/

```
$(function(){
  var palette = ['#66C2A5', '#FC8D62', '#8DA0CB', '#E78AC3', '#A6D854'];
      generateColors = function(){
        var colors = {},
            key;

        for (key in map.regions) {
          colors[key] = palette[Math.floor(Math.random()*palette.length)];
        }
        return colors;
      },
      map;

      map = new jvm.Map({
        map: 'es_merc_en',
        container: $('#map'),
        series: {
          regions: [{
            attribute: 'fill'
          }]
        }
    });

    map.series.regions[0].setValues(generateColors());
    $('#update-colors-button').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     map.series.regions[0].setValues(generateColors());
    });
})
```